# How do I download ksoap2-android source code, to attach in eclipse

Tags: android-ksoap2

On http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/NeedHelp

It says Android Development Toolkit (Eclipse plugin) based environment you will have to manually download the source and javadoc jar files from the [assembly project](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/#svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/).

I have all ready attached the source for my javaSDK (so I believe I know what I'm doing), but I cant find where the source code for ksoap2-android is even given that download link to the assembly project.

What am I missing? Can someone tell me exactly what i should be downloading ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the exact link, attaching in Eclipse hope fully is as easy.

[https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/downloads](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android)

Comment: It was easy to attach. But now I find that there is a bundled component kxml2 which does not have source.

Comment: There aren’t any uploads for this repository.

Comment: @AjayTakur This is a couple of years old, there is probably a newer version now. I'm not actively developing in this area currently so I'll edit the link to point to the root of the repository..